# How to check what applications have access to my clipboard?

Tags: security, clipboard

I was wondering if it was possible for some applications to read the content of my clipboard and the security risks of copying passwords to clipboard. How can I check what processes have access to my clipboard (read/write)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In X11, *everything* has access to your clipboard by default. That's one of the weaknesses (and strengths) of the X11 windowing system - it's obviously insecure, but allows conveniences like clipboard managers. Wayland doesn't allow such total sharing, only the application with focus is notified of clipboard changes.

Comment: So one should never copy sensitive information to clipboard right!?

Comment: @aran ... depends on your threat model. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33429/54387

Comment: You can also use the the autofill functionality of keepassx, which does not use the clipboard.

Comment: Clipboard itself might not be a problem ( especially if you don't install anything suspicious), but what you copy into it  can be.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118/121824